# Send and receive UDP from Web page

Tags: php, flash, udp, activex

I need to send (maybe receive) some data from PHP web page to local software.

This software can receive and send data via UDP port 1987.

Is there a way to do? javascript activeX or flash library or something

Software= VOIP SoftPhone

PHP Web Page = CRM

All I wanted was actually make a button to call and if possible receive the length of the call.

Answer (score 1):

Basicly to read UDP sockets with PHP you need something like:

```
$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP);
socket_bind($sock, $local, $port) or die('Could not bind to address');

while(1) {
    echo socket_read($sock,1024);
}

socket_close($sock);
```

And to send:

```
$frame = array(
    array(1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1),
    array(1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1),
    array(1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1),
    array(1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1),
    array(1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1),
    array(1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1),
    array(1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1),
    array(1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1)
);

send_frame($frame, 1500);

/**
 * Sends 18x8 MCUF-UDP packet to target host.
 *
 * see also:
 * wiki.blinkenarea.org/index.php/MicroControllerUnitFrame
 *
 * @param array    $frame 18x8 '0' or '1'
 * @param int    $delay delay in msec
 * @param string    $host target host
 * @param int    $port target port (udp)
 */
function send_frame($frame, $delay, $host="192.168.0.23", $port=2323) {
    $header = "\x23\x54\x26\x66\x00\x08\x00\x12\x00\x01\x00\xff";
    $buf = $header;
    for ($i=0;$i<8;$i++) {
        for ($j=0;$j<18;$j++) {
            if ($frame[$i][$j]) {
                $buf.="\xff";
            } else  {
                $buf.="\x00";
            }
        }
    }
    $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP);
    socket_sendto($socket, $buf, strlen($buf), 0, $host, $port);
    socket_close($socket);
    usleep($delay*1000);
}
```

Comment: thanx for your answer, im not try yet but i think i need to client side solution. I am trying to when user click a button, triggering a client side softwere